# D3 ordinal scale, left and right margins for tickvalues

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a `x-axis` with ordinal scale just like in this example:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3259783

As you can see the first tick named 'apple' starts from the beginning of the x axis, and the last one 'grapefruit' is at the end.
What I want is some padding left for the first ticks and padding right for the last ticks.

This how I would like to have the axis (also keep in mind that this is an ordinal scale, and I think it's a bit different than time scale or linear)
[image]

This is my code:

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
          .domain(["apple", "orange", "banana", "grapefruit"])
          .rangePoints([0, width]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
              .scale(x)
              .orient("bottom");
```

Answer (score 4):

Per the documenatation https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales you can specify the padding at the beginning and end of the ordinal scale *"as a multiple of the spacing between points"*.

Try:

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
          .domain(["apple", "orange", "banana", "grapefruit"])
          .rangePoints([0, width], 1.0);
```

Comment: Wow man, that's just great . It works exactly as I wanted. I have read their documentation before posting,  but I didn't understand exactly how the rangePoints parameters work.